# Questions in TCP Server in Vert.x

Tags: vert.x

My system is a high speed streaming system in the same Node and the same JVM, I want to use NetServer to receive message and use event bus to forward messages to other Verticle in the same Vertx.

As we know, in Vert.x NetServer is called by event loop thread. I hit an issue. Suppose event bus consumer is slow and NetServer is too fast to send data to event bus, if consumer buffer is full, event bus will discard and lose data. So I am thinking whether there is any way to do flow rate control in NetServer? Or event bus has a back pressure to NetServer to slow down sending to event bus.

I appreciate your ideas and comments.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, Vert.x EventBus doesn't drop messages for local consumers.

Although the documentation states that `DEFAULT_ACCEPT_BACKLOG` is set to 1024, it's actually -1:

https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/1ab9884cb29adea75b378c3fa7359813f3de68f9/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/net/NetServerOptions.java#L45

And I don't see that it's being used anywhere to limit size of EventBus.

You can also use this test to make sure all messages actually arrive:

```
public class BackpressureExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setEventBusOptions(new EventBusOptions().setAcceptBacklog(1)));

        vertx.deployVerticle(new SlowConsumer(), new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true), h -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
                vertx.eventBus().send("address", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }
            System.out.println("Done producing");
        });
    }

    private static class SlowConsumer extends AbstractVerticle {

        @Override
        public void start() {
            AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
            this.vertx.eventBus().consumer("address", h -> {
                System.out.println(counter.incrementAndGet());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You can see how message are delivered to local consumers here:
https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/impl/EventBusImpl.java#L359

Comment: You can read my article on it: https://medium.com/@alexey.soshin/understanding-vert-x-event-bus-c31759757ce8
If you like source code, best place to start is here: https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/impl/EventBusImpl.java#L420

Comment: Thanks your reply. Obviously, if data is not be lost, data should be save somewhere. where they are buffered and saved? How big size for this buffer? and is there any interface to change buffer size?

Comment: Messages are not buffered. What it means is that if there are no listeners at the moment, message will be lost. They are executed on `TaskQueue`, and it's a linked list without capacity: https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/impl/TaskQueue.java#L48